# Paypal express checkout, Invalid Return and Cancel URL's - Laravel

Tags: php, paypal

I am currently working with the Paypal express checkout API in my laravel app and I have come to a sticking point. The data I am getting from Paypal is:

```
array:13 [▼
  "TIMESTAMP" => "2016-02-23T10:24:12Z"
  "CORRELATIONID" => "fc57735d8b192"
  "ACK" => "Failure"
  "VERSION" => "104.0"
  "BUILD" => "18316154"
  "L_ERRORCODE0" => "10471"
  "L_ERRORCODE1" => "10472"
  "L_SHORTMESSAGE0" => "Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details."
  "L_SHORTMESSAGE1" => "Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details."
  "L_LONGMESSAGE0" => "ReturnURL is invalid."
  "L_LONGMESSAGE1" => "CancelURL is invalid."
  "L_SEVERITYCODE0" => "Error"
  "L_SEVERITYCODE1" => "Error"
]
```

^^ As you can see I am getting 2 errors for invalid Return and Cancel URL's

My URL's are:

```
$requestParams = array(
     'RETURNURL' => 'mindfullness.app/checkout/order-review',
     'CANCELURL' => 'mindfullness.app/checkout'
);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Your answers are appreciated

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

**I needed to add 'http://' to the URL's**

```
$requestParams = array(
     'RETURNURL' => 'http://mindfullness.app/checkout/order-review',
     'CANCELURL' => 'http://mindfullness.app/checkout'
);
```